# Subversion errors dlls missing

Tags: svn

After checking out a project from another developer, we often get some dlls missing that are present on his machine but when I search for them on my local machine, they are not there. These are standard Microsoft dlls.

Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Common

Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.ServiceManager.UI.Console

Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.Core

Microsoft.ScriptManager.MSAjax

Microsoft.ScriptManager.WebForms

But when I go to look for the dlls above, they are not on my machine but yet when I create a new asp.net project (using VS2012), these dlls are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be following reasons for this:-

- Another developer is referring these dlls from his local folder ( instead of GAC etc ) and he have not checked-in these dlls in SVN. Hence you do not get them on checkout/update
- Also check for the referenced path/location of these dlls from your  VS2012 solution.
- As these are standard Microsoft dlls, your VS2012 is picking them up from .net reference library when you are creating any new project.